# create multiples conditions in PHP

Tags: php, sql, checkbox, conditional-statements

My application use notification. You have 3 checkboxes to determine what types of notifications you want ("followers", "subscribers", "donators"). You can check all of them or just one or two...

Checkboxes status are sent on a php file with an ajax function in post data. (if a checkbox is checked, return 1, else 0).

In my php file I need to check my database, but before check it, I need to know if I have to check followers only, or subscribers too, or donators, or all, or two of them, etc...

Instead of creating a huge list of conditions, I'm looking for an easier solution to know what to check in dbb desparately...

```
$currentuser=json_decode(stripcslashes($_POST['currentuser'])); //return the name of the user
$follow_mode = json_decode(stripcslashes($_POST['follow'])); //return 1 or 0
$subscribe_mode = json_decode(stripcslashes($_POST['subscribe'])); //return 1 or 0
$donation_mode = json_decode(stripcslashes($_POST['donation'])); //return 1 or 0

$req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE seen=:seen AND target=:tgt ORDER BY id DESC');
$req->execute(array(':seen'=>false,':tgt'=>$currentuser));
```

In my table of my dbb, I have "is_follower", "is_sub", "is_donator" with "1" or "0" value inside. The use of "AND" in SQL request is impossible, because if for example all the checkboxes are checked ,the notification must be follower and sub and donator at the same time.

What is the easy way to make a good conditions?

Comment: The question is too broad for here. Try to break it down and ask relevant questions about the things that you can't solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without completely understanding why you could not use the AND statement in your SQL query, I've been able to limit it to 7 scenarios.

```
if($follow_mode == 1 && $subscribe_mode == 1 && $donation_mode == 1) {
 $sqlquery = 1;
}
if($follow_mode == 1 && $subscribe_mode == 1 && $donation_mode == 0) {
 $sqlquery = 2;
}

if($follow_mode == 1 && $subscribe_mode == 0 && $donation_mode == 1) {
 $sqlquery = 3;
}

if($follow_mode == 0 && $subscribe_mode == 1 && $donation_mode == 1) {
 $sqlquery = 4;
}


if($follow_mode == 0 && $subscribe_mode == 0 && $donation_mode == 1) {
 $sqlquery = 5;
}


if($follow_mode == 0 && $subscribe_mode == 1 && $donation_mode == 0) {
 $sqlquery = 6;
}


if($follow_mode == 1 && $subscribe_mode == 0 && $donation_mode == 0) {
 $sqlquery = 7;
}

if($sqlquery == 1) {
 //run query where follow_mode == 1, subscribe_mode == 1, donation_mode == 1
}

//continue until $sqlquery 7
```